# Python script doesn't write on a shared folder by windows scheduler

Tags: python

I have develop a script python that read file by a ftp connection and after unzip the files and write into a specific folder that is stored into other server. I have create a shared folder and as path to write file I use the path of shared folder `\\servername\Users\Users1\folderName`.
When I run the script by Python IDLE the script work fine and write all file into shared folder, but when I set a task scheduler with windows, the script run but doesn't write on a shared folder on the other server. The shared folder have all permission. Any help?

Comment: What user is running the scheduled task? Maybe that user has no access to the folder you are trying to write to?

Comment: The task is create by Administrator user of machine that run script. This user by the server that run script read fine the the shared folder